# Mobile to Mobile Remote Access using Android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sharing, remote-access

i am developing an APP in Android which share screen to all android mobile phone connected in a session.

i want to know that android provides any sdk which provides same service like desktop to dektop access as in team View  ?

or any Idea, which SDK i have to used?

Thank you.

Comment: is there any solution for this?now i have same requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Smartphones can't directly connect to each others since they are running in different networks. The common way to solve this is an additional server component. All phones need to connect to the server and send their data. The server is pushing this data to other connected clients, probably by using push notifications. In Android Push Notifications are known as C2DM.

Android developers blog:

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/05/android-cloud-to-device-messaging.html

Here's another tutorial on the topic:

http://www.zylinc.com/blog-reader/items/c2dm-a-simple-introduction-using-a-java-server.html

Comment: But my Question is still there..
its means i cant develop an Android app which provides mobile to mobile remote access same like pc to pc by teamviewer?

Comment: I have read these articles on C2DM but i have found that it is for very little size messaging like notification sending .. i have to send snapshot of mobile phone and have share it to their connected clients

Comment: With the push notification you don't send the actual data. It's only a notification that there's something new. Once a device receives a push notification it usually connects to the server and downloads the data.

Answer (score 0):

I like [2X RDP](http://www.motoask.com/motorola-xoom-updates-f65/2x-client-rdp-remote-desktop-t4069.html) a lot. It works very well on phone and tablet and connects to the regular Windows RDP server, so don’t have to install anything else on the server machine.

Comment: but i want implementation detail in Android??